# Cannot access to Herokuapp config vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have deployed a React + Express project to Heroku and after setting up the environment variables the application won't read this config vars.

The project is working currently using Express to serve the production build, so my package.json `start` line is just `node server.js`.

Then I have tried to log (`console.log(process.env)`) whatever I config in the **Settings** > **Config Vars** (according to [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars)) from my dashboard and nothing more than `NODE_ENV` is displayed in the console.

[image]

This is my Express code, which serves the static build:

```js
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const compression = require('compression');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(logger(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'dev' : 'combined'));
app.use(compression());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 10000, () => { console.log('Server started'); } );
```

Any clues of what's going on?

Comment: Hi, are you calling the variables using this synthax `process.env.OTHER_VAR` in your actual code? Could you please post your port configuration for your Express app, specifically the `app.listen(...)` method ?

Comment: @AndrésMuñoz, I have edited the post and pasted what my Express code looks like.